# How can I use LIKE with an arbitrary word order in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to use the `LIKE` keyword or some other similar operator for this purpose:

In the database, the name and surname is stored as one column and it's in the order `surname name` (e.g. "Doe John").

I have a search bar with lets you enter your name and surname. When I am going to search, I require that if you enter `name surname` instead of `surname name` (e.g. if you enter "John Doe"), I still want the same results to show up as if you had written `surname name`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you wish to know how to use the LIKE or how to swap (surname name) to (name surname)

Comment: No actually I know how to use the LIKE. However I thought at first that you can do this with the LIKE. Therefore I want to know how to swap surname name to name surname

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your table is `MyISAM`, you can create a `FULLTEXT` index on both fields:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable (name, surname)
```

and issue this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(name, surname) AGAINST ('+John +Doe' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will return both `John Doe` and `Doe John`.

On a `MyISAM` table this query will work even without creating the index, however, in this case it will be much more slow.

**Update:**

This will work even if you have name and surname in a single field:

```
CREATE TABLE t_name (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT
INTO    t_name
VALUES
(1, 'John Doe'),
(2, 'Doe John');

SELECT  *
FROM    t_name
WHERE   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+John +Doe' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

1, 'John Doe'
2, 'Doe John'
```

**Update 2:**

On an `InnoDB` table, you can use regular expressions:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_name
WHERE   name RLIKE '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]'
        AND name RLIKE '[[:<:]]Doe[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: I don't have two fields. I have only one field named Name which contains both name and surname. That is my problem...

Comment: Chris, this FULLTEXT option works with your one NAME column, just fine.  It will also work if some of your names have three or more words in them, like "John Fitzgerald (Jack) Kennedy"

Comment: Ok will try this out then. Will let you know if I succeed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Original Data:

**name**

```
Doe John
Stack Overflow
Pew Ned
```

Record to search

```
declare @String2Search varchar(50)
set @String2Search = 'John Doe'
```

**Sql Sever Query**

```
select name from @t 
where REPLACE(name,' ','') like '%' + REPLACE(@String2Search,' ','') + '%'
OR
SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name),len(name)) + SUBSTRING(name,0,CHARINDEX(' ',name))  like '%' + REPLACE(@String2Search,' ','') + '%'
```

**MySql Query**

```
select name from @t 
where REPLACE(name,' ','') like '%' + REPLACE(@String2Search,' ','') + '%'
OR 

SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(' ',name),LENGTH(name)) + SUBSTRING(name,0,LOCATE(' ',name))  like '%' + REPLACE(@String2Search,' ','') + '%'
```

Note- I am a sql server guy. so first I wrote the query in SQL SERVER and then I checked in google for the corresponding function equivalence in MYSQL and I just replaced those

like

```
SQLSERVER ---------------------------------------------- MYSQL



SUBSTRING() ------------Equivalent----------------------- SUBSTRING() 



CHARINDEX() ------------Equivalent----------------------- LOCATE()


REPLACE() --------------Equivalent----------------------- REPLACE()


LEN() --------------Equivalent----------------------- LENGTH()
```

In Sql Server it is working fine. The concept I implemented is I am matching the word from the search text against First Name and Last Name as well as the reverse (Last Name & First Name)

I have used Replace function to remove any spaces between the charecters

This statement(in sql server)

```
SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name),len(name)) + SUBSTRING(name,0,CHARINDEX(' ',name))
```

OR

in MY SQL

```
SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(' ',name),LENGTH(name)) + SUBSTRING(name,0,LOCATE(' ',name))
```

is basically converting the First and LastName to LastName followed by First Name

Hope you got the concept and it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_name
WHERE   name LIKE '%john%' AND name LIKE '%doe%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//in PHP
//after filtering and validating name and surname
$where = 'WHERE name = ' .$name. ' ' .$surname. ' OR name = ' .$surname. ' ' .$name;
```

Check for both.

Comment: Yes I know about that solution but for some reasons it would be complicated at this point to split the name. Remember that the name is one attribute containing both name and surname. Isn't there a way how can you do this directly from SQL?

Comment: @Chris: You're going to have to split the name at some point. At least in this case it's just a matter of splitting the input string on a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1)
SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1)
```

Negative value as the count (3rd variable) returns everything right of the space.  Positive values return everything to the left.

This is assuming you have a single field where you input both values.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the search input at whitespace and search for each word separately. You'd have to write a simple function to generate the statement. Basically, if you'd search for:

```
Luke Skywalker
```

The statement you'd get would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE
    (`name` LIKE "Luke%" OR `name` LIKE "Skywalker%")
    AND
    (`surname` LIKE "Luke%" OR `surname` LIKE "Skywalker%")
```

If someone searches for three words (or one word only) you'd have three (or one) LIKE statements per field. And if you want to be less strict and you only require one of the words to match, replace the `AND` with an `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are using but the context/main idea should stay the same.
You could add 2 text boxes, 1 for name and 1 for surname.
Then you should use a LIKE query that searches for your text box name and surname value in that order.

EDIT:

A second way is to split up the content of the textbox and save them in 2 separate strings.
Then search for it using something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <your table> WHERE names LIKE 'name1+" "+name2' OR WHERE names LIKE 'name2+" "+name1';
```

Comment: I don't think it's a user friendly option to add two fields. (Maybe on an advanced search page)

Comment: that's right, it might always be another way to detect whether there are 2 words typed into the textbox, split them and search them in either direction using an OR in the query. 
then again the name could consist of 3 or even 4 words.

Comment: There are some names which contains 2 names and 2 surnames. How will you split a name like that? Names aren't consistant. For instance, you might have a name john w doe or you might have another name john michael doe johns. How will split these as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL = "Select * From T_Name " & GetSuperWhere("Name", "John Smith")


Private Function GetSuperWhere(FieldName As String, Words As String) As String
    Dim X() As String
    Dim Where As String = ""
    'sample: GetSuperWhere('Name', 'John Smith') -> Return: 
    '   " WHERE Name Like '%John%' AND Name Like '%Doe%'"


    X = Words.Split(" ")
    For Each Word As String In X
        If Where <> "" Then Where = Where & " AND "
        Where = Where & FieldName & " Like '%" & Word & "%'"
    Next


    If Where <> "" Then Where = " WHERE " & Where


    Return Where
End Function
```